# Comunicación entre 2 aplicaciones WPF y C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Quiero hacer que 2 aplicaciones (cliente y servidor) tengan comunicación para que la aplicación cliente le mande a la servidor reporte de ventas, datos de los usuarios y otras cosas y el servidor se actualice dinamicamente y le llegue notificación se que se realizo una venta/impresion (ejemplo) y todo esto regularmente están entre la misma red local en diferentes pc para un servicio de negocio que se aplica en un cyber, papeleria y otros negocios.

otro cliente no necesita saber nada del otro cliente solo la aplicacion cliente debe saber si inicio turno el servidor y si esta conectado para que el mismo pueda bindar servicio y cobro, y ademas porque el servidor debe ser capas de hacer un cierre de turno e imprimir los totales de cada venta y costo total del dia por el servicio que estoy dando en offline osea solo en una red local de un cyber, papeleria, etc.

Para ello CREO YO que opte que la comunicación fuera mediante la misma dinamica que se utiliza en chats como lo muestra en los videos siguientes

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIL69aUL3N4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdcafc_eAhw
```

pero no se si sea buena idea debido que al intentar correrlo se queda esperando todo el tiempo la entrada de un nuevo usuario en la red osea en la linea de código siguiente.

```
client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

o realmente debo hacerlo de otra forma y me gustaría saber como, de favor ¡ayuda!.

Comment: cual es el objetivo que el cliente envie reportes y datos a servidor ? porque para eso no necesitas socket, podrias usar una base de datos central y los cliente insertan o consultan los datos de esta

Comment: actualice la pregunta

Comment: una duda, porque solo te quedaste con ese ejemplo de youtube? no encontraste algun otro, no lo he visto completo, pero como sabes que es lo que buscas sino lo comparas con algo mas?

Comment: realmente necesitas una comunicacion en tiempo real? porque quizas un cliente podria poner los datos y si otro cliente quiere verlos solo se los listas pero a pedido de este, no que recibe una notificacion en tiempo real cuando se produce todas las acciones

Comment: Mira lo que pasas es que otro cliente no necesita saber nada del otro cliente solo la aplicacion cliente debe saber si inicio turno el servidor  y si esta conectado para que el mismo pueda bindar servicio y cobro, y ademas porque el servidor debe ser capas de hacer un cierre de turno e imprimir los totales de cada venta y costo total de la venta por el servicio que estoy dando en offline osea solo en una red local de un cyber, papeleria, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si necesitas comunicar el cliente con el servidor para enviar acciones de uno al otro podrias aplicar `SignalR`

Si bien al buscar sobre esta tecnologia esta pensada para desarrollo web, puede ser implementada en aplicaciones desktop.

La ventaja de esta tecnologia es que el servidor expone un `localhost:8080` (o el puerto que definas) y los cliente se conectan a este estableciendo un canal de comunicacion que quedara activo, de esta forma no necesitas que el cliente exponga su propio puerto, simplificando la comunicacion.

[Using SignalR in WinForms and WPF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b)

Entre el cliente-servidor se establece una comunicacion por medio de socket, pero la libreria abstrae la funcioanlidad puediendo enviar acciones

La idea es definir un `Hub` que recibira las conexiones de los clientes

```
public class MyHub : Hub 
{ 
    public void Send(string name, string message) 
    { 
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message); 
    } 
    public override Task OnConnected() 
    { 
        //codigo
        return base.OnConnected(); 
    } 
    public override Task OnDisconnected() 
    { 
        //codigo
        return base.OnDisconnected(); 
    } 
}
```

asi podrias enviar a todos o a uno en particular una accion desde el servidor

Si necesitas enviar una accion a un cliente en concreto deberas poder resolver cual es el id de la conexion

[Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

para eso conservas el id en una lista en memoria para lueg buscar a quien quieres enviar la accion